# onActivityResult can't triggered when add flutter module to android project

Tags: android, flutter

step:

1.add a plugin created myself to flutter module project

2.run it, and onActivityResult can invoke

3.add flutter module project to android

4.run it, and onActivityResult can't invoke

demo projects:

flutter module with a simple plugin, look at [testplugin](https://github.com/longdw/testplugin)

android project with flutter module, look at [TestPluginAndroid](https://github.com/longdw/TestPluginAndroid)

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, override `onActivityResult` in Activity,  and do it the following way:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        mFlutterView.getPluginRegistry().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FlutterFragment, in Native app, then  you may call below method.

```
flutterFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity do you call the super method of onActivityResult ?

```kotlin
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        ...
        
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```